# Using Ember.js, how do I manually scope a template and view to its corresponding controller?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ember.js, handlebars.js

Let's say I initiate a controller:

```
    App.pageController = Ember.Controller.create({

         pageNumber:  '12',
    })
```

And its corresponding view:

```
    App.pageView = Ember.View.create({

        templateName: 'page-template',

    }).append();
```

And now its template:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name = 'page-template'>
        <div class = 'page-background'>
            page: {{ pageNumber }}
        </div>
    </script>
```

I intend for pageController to provide the rendering context for pageView, however I do not know how to explicitly provide the instructions for this, and as a result pageNumber is not rendered.

I could go around this by putting a pageNumberBinding in pageView:

```
   App.pageView = Ember.View.create({

        templateName: 'page-template',
        pageNumberBinding: 'App.pageController.pageNumber',

    }).append();
```

And rewrite the template as follows

```
 page: {{ pageNumber contextBinding="this" }}
```

But how would you do it the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the `controller` property on the view, the view will forward the properties it doesn't know about to the controller.

So, using your example, you could do:

```
App.pageView = Ember.View.create({
    controller:   App.pageController,
    templateName: 'page-template',
}).append();
```

Check out the [Ember docs for Ember.View](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View), and the [introduction on their site](http://emberjs.com/documentation/).